# ItemChange in Outlook VSTO AddIn gets called several times after save to appointmentItem

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

in my Addin I attached to the ItemChange event like this;

```
public void attachEvents()
        {
           _CalendarItems.ItemChange += Item_Change;
```

and I wrote a function like this:

```
public void Item_Add(Object item)
        {
            Outlook.AppointmentItem myAppointment = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            if (myAppointment != null)
            {
```

[...]

My problem is that this method does not get called just once when I call myAppointment.save() but 3-4 times. Why is that?

And there are only get() calls in the eventhandler so there is NOTHING changed in the appointmentItem (which would probably trigger further events of course).

Best regards
Hannes

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. Especially with Exchange profiles configured in Outlook. You may find similar forum threads like the following one - [Outlook 2016 produces an extra ItemChange event after an appointment is created](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/901d03a3-8e9b-4d27-8c91-76f876ec38fe/outlook-2016-produces-an-extra-itemchange-event-after-an-appointment-is-created?forum=outlookdev#04aa1f24-a4dc-4a5d-aa32-f463a8351d6c).